# Add JAVA_HOME to path on Mac Sierra

Tags: macos

I want to add JAVA_HOME directory to my path. I know there are a lot of questions on this and I also tried the answers, but none seems to work for me.

I have tried a lot, at the moment my .bash_profile looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@6/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/3859397,26.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home)
```

typing

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

gives the following outcome:

```
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory
```

and `echo $JAVA_HOME` displays nothing, just an empty line. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `$(` and the `)`. So, the correct line is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
```